# Url mapping in web forms - allow question marks and hyphens

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, url-routing

I have implemented URL mapping in our ASP.NET 4 application, but I have a problem with some of our content.

Some of our products has a hyphen "-" or a question mark "?" in them. It's not an option to remove that. A productname could be "*My Product - Good for you?*".

We use two custom made methods, *MakeUrlSeoReady* and *MakeUrlNonSeoReady*. We replace space like this: Replace(" ","-"), as this is the most SEO-friendly solution. However, we also need to make this work with both question marks and hyphens.

The reason we use the MakeUrlSeoReady / NonReady methods is to be able to show the "real" name.

Currently the mapping is defined as follows:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Produkt visning",
                    "artikler/{Categoryname}/{SubCategoryname}/{ProductName}",
                    "~/SingleProduct.aspx");
```

So what I do is I retrieve the product depending on the ProductName. I use two methods I've created:

```
    public static string MakeUrlNonSeoReady(string text)
    {
        return text.ToLower().
           Replace("oe", "ø").
           Replace("aa", "å").
           Replace("ae", "æ").
           Replace("-", " ");
    }

    public static string MakeUrlSeoReady(string text)
    {
        return text.ToLower().
            Replace("ø", "oe").
            Replace("å", "aa").
            Replace("æ", "ae").
            Replace(" ", "-");
    }
```

So in the SingleProduct.aspx page I use the following string to get from our database:

```
string categoryName = HelperFunctions.MakeUrlNonSeoReady(Page.RouteData.Values["ProductName"]);
```

But this will of course not work. So any help is really appreciated :-)

Comment: A "?" in a URL specifies a query string. You're not going to be able to change how IIS handles parsing your requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arguably cleaner and simpler method is to use a unique product identifier that is numerical or alphanumerical and is natively HTML encoded, and then simply put the product name as an unused parameter for SEO or search purposes.

MSDN [RouteCollection.MapPageRoute Method (String, String, String, Boolean, RouteValueDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784594.aspx)

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Produkt visning", 
                "artikler/{Categoryname}/{SubCategoryname}/{ProductIdentifier}/{ProductName}", 
                "~/SingleProduct.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary 
    { { "ProductName ", string.Empty } });
```

Comment: Is that possible? Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Its common, I use the same format often in MVC projects, especially where there are non English names etc.